# Understanding details of PCA - variance

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I am currently reading through [Principal Component Analysis, Second Edition](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MV_Probability/MVsa_Statistics%20and%20applications/Jolliffe%20I.%20Principal%20Component%20Analysis%20%282ed.,%20Springer,%202002%29%28518s%29_MVsa_.pdf) and came to small paragraph that I do not fully understand on page 5 (Section 1.1):

"To derive the form of the PCs, consider first $\alpha_1'x$; the vector ${\alpha_1}$ maximizes $\textrm{var}[\alpha_1'x] = \alpha_1'\sum\alpha_1$. **It is clear that, as it stands, the maximum will not be achieved for finite $\alpha_1$ so a normalization constraint must be imposed**."

I am sure I am over-thinking this, but it is not clear to me at all. Why cannot the maximum be achieved for finite $\alpha_1x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose some finite $\alpha_1$ maximizes $\operatorname{var}[x\Sigma]$ for some covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Take $k > 1$ and consider $\operatorname{var}[k\alpha_1\Sigma] = k^2\alpha_1'\Sigma\alpha_1$. Since $k^2 > 1$, then $\operatorname{var}[k\alpha_1\Sigma] > \operatorname{var}[\alpha_1\Sigma]$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: So as long as α1 is finite, there is always some k such that var[kα1Σ] > var[α1Σ]?

Comment: Yeah, simple scalar-vector multiplication shows this to be true. This is why we must impose the constraints.